# XPath for parent's sibling descendants

Tags: html, web-scraping, xpath, multiple-axes

I have the following HTML I need to scrape, but the only reliable handle is a stable description of a text field. From there, I need to go to its parent, find that parents next sibling and then get the descendents (unfortunately the `data-automation-id` selector repeats in every such iteration of this snippet on the site). I put together the below XPath but my RPA tool is unable to find it in the document.

**XPath**

```
div[contains(text(),'STABLE TEXT HANDLE')]/following-sibling::div/div/div/span[data-automation-id="SOMETHING"]
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <div>
          <label>STABLE TEXT HANDLE</label>
      </div>
      <div>
          <div>
              <div>
                  <span></span>
                  <span data-automation-id="something">
                      <div>
                          <div>
                              <div>
                                  DYNAMIC TEXT I WANT TO SCRAPE
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </span>
                  <span data-automation-id="somethingelse">
                      <div>
                          <div>
                              <div>
                                  DYNAMIC TEXT I WANT TO SCRAPE
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </span>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT:**

After futher testing, it seems the issue starts with the `contains(text(),'STABLE TEXT HANDLE')`, which fails to find that particular node (be it the `label`, or its parent `div`).

Comment: Add `//` at the beginning of the XPath expression. See my answer!

Comment: @Prophet I am working with Openbots.ai and it allows both ```tag[selector='']``` and ```//tag[@selector='']```

Comment: So I see finally it worked?

Comment: Yes. It was one of those things that you copy-paste (and check for typos and all) and they do not work at all. You fiddle with a lot of variants, none of them work either, then you reverse back to the original copy-pasted variant... and it just starts working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
//label[contains(text(),'STABLE TEXT HANDLE')]/../..//span[@data-automation-id="something"]
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand - this goes to the parent ```div```, then to the parent ```li```, and from there it searches for descendant with that particular selector, right?

Comment: Correct, exactly.